# I can't boot Ubuntu from external HDD

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, usb, uefi

I can't boot Ubuntu from my external USB3 HDD.

I need to install it for UEFI, but after instalation from LiveCD it doesn't boot.

I ran *Boot Info Script* - [Pastebin](http://paste.ubuntu.com/15197875/)
and then i tried *Boot-repair* - [Pastebin](http://paste.ubuntu.com/15190101/)
but it still doesn't work, please help. (sorry for bad english)

Answer (score 0):

In your bios boot option can you choose between uefi boot and legacy boot?

If so try legacy boot and give the install usb stick a try

Comment: But i need uefi

Answer (score 0):

I think you may have done a cross-mode installation, with Windows in EFI mode and Ubuntu in BIOS mode, but I'm not positive of that -- there are conflicting indicators in your output. Here's my recommendation:

1. Download the USB flash drive or CD-R version of my [rEFInd boot manager.](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/getting.html) (Download links for both formats exist on that page.)
2. Prepare a boot medium from what you download.
3. Boot to the rEFInd medium. With any luck, it will show options for booting both Windows and Ubuntu. If you don't see an Ubuntu option that shows `vmlinuz` as part of the description, hit the Esc key.
4. Test the Windows option, and then the Ubuntu option. Note that there may be two Ubuntu options, and perhaps other strays. It's important only that you can get into each OS, not that all the options work.
5. If you can boot both Windows and Ubuntu, then boot to Ubuntu and install the rEFInd PPA or Debian package.

At this point, rEFInd should take over as your default boot manager, and you should be able to boot both OSes. If there are redundant or non-functional options in the rEFInd menu, you can clean them up, as described [here.](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/configfile.html#hiding)

It may also be possible to fix the problem with Boot Repair, but you'd end up with a system that would become harder to boot whenever you unplug your external disk. In this case, rEFInd is a superior solution, because if you unplug the external disk, the direct-kernel boot bath in rEFInd will disappear, leaving Windows still bootable.